# C# - Export class definition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, rest

I have a several Entity Framework classes in my application and I need to create REST APIs that allow access to the definition of some of these classes. I have no issues returning normal objects via REST APIs, however, I'm not sure how to return the definition of an object. The end goal is for the application consuming the APIs call to compare the object definition. Any pointers in this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to look into OData. Typically it's easy to hook up an Entity Framework Context as an OData endpoint, and there's a whole standard with OData for discovering the shape of all the entities and issuing queries against them.

Answer (score 1):

To share how it will look like the return dto with the consumer of your API, you can do it nicely with a [Swagger documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example?